# Compute distance traversed before reaching specific max speed based on linear acceleration

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a linear acceleration (lets say 2000cm/s), and a max speed (lets say 360cm/s).

Initial velocity magnitude can vary. The direction doesn't change.

How do I figure out the distance that would be traversed upon reaching the velocity magnitude of 360cm/s with an acceleration of 2000cm/s from arbitrary starting velocity?

There is no concept of time required, only distance.

I have looked at a lot of similar algorithms but I can't find anything that covers this exact concept.

Comment: @hardmath That sounds correct

Comment: Acceleration measures change in speed per time, so $(\mathrm{cm}/\mathrm{s})/\mathrm{s}$ or $\mathrm{cm}/\mathrm{s}^2$.

Comment: A typical application of this problem is to determine the distance travelled by a free falling object (constant acceleration) given the final velocity.  For example [Establish traveled distance from velocity knowing constant acceleration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648769/establish-traveled-distance-from-velocity-knowing-constant-acceleration).